# Binding to UserControl properties from calling page

Tags: .net, wpf, user-controls, dependency-properties

I created a user control that has a dependency property.  I can set the property in the calling page fine, and everything works correctly within the user control.  However, when a dependency property value is changed, the page that hosts the user control is not notified.

The dependency property in the user control is:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedSearchResultProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedSearchResult", typeof(SearchResult), typeof(QPowerFinder), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnSelectedSearchResultChanged));
public SearchResult SelectedSearchResult
{
    get { return (SearchResult)this.GetValue(SelectedSearchResultProperty); }
    set
    {
        this.SetValue(SelectedSearchResultProperty, value);
        RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedSearchResult");
    }
}
private static void OnSelectedSearchResultChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
    (obj as QPowerFinder).SelectedSearchResult = (SearchResult)args.NewValue;
}
```

The page hosting the user control is set up as:

```
<localcont:QPowerFinder Grid.Column="1" SelectedSearchResult="{Binding BoxAccountResult, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

The hoped for behavior would be the dependency property registers the change, and it notifies the hosting page through the binding. However, it's not.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A `DependencyProperty` is more like a pointer to another property

You can have it point to your external `BoxAccountResult` property, or you can have it point to `(SearchResult)args.NewValue`, but you can't do both.

I think what you're looking to do is to update the source `SelectedSearchResult` property in the `OnSelectedSearchResultChanged` method instead of setting the property to a new value.

Comment: A DependencyProperty is more like a pointer to another property

You can have it point to your external BoxAccountResult property, or you can have it point to (SearchResult)args.NewValue, but you can't do both. 

I think what you're looking to do is to update the source SelectedSearchResult property in the OnSelectedSearchResultChanged method instead of setting the property to a new value
   sounds about right - but I am not sure what to do differently?

Comment: @billp What's the purpose of the `OnSelectedSearchResultChanged`, and who calls this? You may not even need it at all. But if I remember correctly, there's some way of getting the Binding Expression and using `UpdateSource` or `UpdateTarget` to update the source property, but I can't remember the syntax right now.